# RecyclerView update items on scroll only

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, camera

I think I've read all the answers to all of the similar questions, and none of them seem to be fixing my problem,they're only workaround. I have recycler view with pictures taken by camera and they only update on scroll.

Using a smoothScrollToPosition() is workaround and I want to know the cause of this issue and fix it.

It's really weird because when a open my fragment and have a couple of images in the recycler view which I added earlier, deleting elements works perfect, but when I add new image from camera intent even the notification for deleting stops working, I have to do a scroll to refresh items in the adapter.

This is the part where I set the data:

```
viewModel.photos.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    list->adapter.data = list
}).
```

Of course data is set in OnUiThread :

I checked with the debugger-- elements in list are updated.

Does anyone know the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell `recyclerView.adapter` what exactly changed by calling [notifyItemChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)). There are also other methods for inserted items, moved items, deleted items, etc. You can look at the full documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html):

There is also another way by implementing a [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil). You can research about it more. But the difference is that by using `DiffUtil`, you won't have to manually call those notify methods yourself.

Also, the old/unoptimized/unrecomenended way to do this is to simply call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

P.S. I highly think you found the somewhat the same answer while searching online and might have thought it as simply "a work around". I'm here to tell you that this is how its supposed to be handled.

Comment: I check earlier notifyItemInserted,notifyItemRemoved and this doesn't work properly in my problem,sometimes this lines refresh adapter but usually they don't.Also I check DiffUtil and nothings change.Only method which help is ` private fun requestLayout(view:View){
        view.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.measuredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.measuredHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))
        view.layout(view.left, view.top, view.right, view.bottom)
    }` and call it after setData.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want those methods. The "sometimes" works maybe because of a wrong index passed to the method. Have you tried the ultimate notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Also you might want to update your question with your current progress.